# getting means of matched columns in different dataframes

Tags: r

How can I get the means of 3 different dataframes? I tried:

```
df1<-data.frame(c(1,2,3),c(1,7,3),c(rep(1,3)))
colnames(df1)<-c("c1","c2","c3")
df2<-data.frame(c(5,5,5),c(1,3,4),c(rep(1,3)))
colnames(df2)<-c("c1","c2","c3")
df3<-data.frame(c(2,5,2),c(1,1,1),c(rep(1,3)))
colnames(df3)<-c("c1","c2","c3")
#m3<-m3[!(is.na(m3[,3])|is.na(m3[,4])),]
#m3[!duplicated(m3$c1),]

cbind(apply(data.frame(df1,df2,df3), 1, mean))
```

which gave me the means of everything in the row. My goal is to get the means of the matching row eg mean of (df1[,1] and df2[,1] and df[,3]) for each column.

What I was hoping for is:

```
      c1.mean    c2.mean   c3.mean
row1    2.67         1       1
row2      4         3.67     1
row3    3.33        2.67    1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setNames(round((df1+df2+df3)/3,digit=2),paste0('c',1:3,'.mean'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are more datasets, we can place them in a `list`, `+` with `Reduce` and divide by the n number of datasets.

```
setNames(round(Reduce('+', mget(ls(pattern='df\\d+')))/3,2),
                          paste0(names(df1), '.mean'))
#  c1.mean c2.mean c3.mean
#1    2.67    1.00       1
#2    4.00    3.67       1
#3    3.33    2.67       1
```

The above method may not be the best when you have NAs in the dataset.  If there are NA values, we could convert the `list` to `array` and use `apply` with `rowMeans` and `na.rm=TRUE`

```
res <- round(apply(array(unlist(mget(ls(pattern='df\\d+'))), 
               dim=c(dim(df1), 3)), 2, rowMeans, na.rm=TRUE),2)
res 
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] 2.67 1.00    1
#[2,] 4.00 3.67    1
#[3,] 3.33 2.67    1

colnames(res) <- paste0(names(df1), '.mean')
```